# How to store WebElements in an array

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I just wanted to know how to store the following webElements in an array.

```
 WebElement NameLbl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Name')]"));
            WebElement MobLbl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Mobile')]"));
            WebElement LookingLbl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Looking for ')]"));
            WebElement GenderLbl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Gender')]"));
            WebElement MandatoryList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'*')]"));
```

I am trying to store this using the below line but it is giving an error.

```
List<WebElement> ExpList=new ArrayList<WebElement>() {NameLbl,MobLbl,LookingLbl,GenderLbl};
```

Comment: What error is it showing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate lists like that.

What you were probably going for was this:

```
List<WebElement> ExpList = List.of(NameLbl, MobLbl, LookingLbl, GenderLbl);
```

Which converts the arguments you've passed into the correct type of list.

Comment: Thanks, this is working . Can you please explain what I was doing wrong and also what does List.of() do ?

Comment: I assume you were trying the array technique of initializing a collection i.e. `int[] arr = {0, 1, 2}`, but this is not syntactically correct for lists. `List.of`returns a List containing the elements you pass to it, and of the same type as the elements. I assume if the elements are of different types it causes an error, but don't quote me on that :)

Answer (score 0):

I wound suggest another approach..

You can use the approach suggested by Robo Mop, however **this won't let you to modify that list later**. Assume you have the code:

```java
List<Object> objectList = Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object());
objectList.add(new Object());
System.out.println(objectList);
```

The code above would throw the exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
> at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)
> at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111)

Instead I would suggest to use this appraoch:

```java
List<Object> objectList = Stream.of(new Object(), new Object()).collect(Collectors.toList());
objectList.add(new Object());
System.out.println(objectList);
```

This would create `ArrayList` object like you do you your trial.